# Looking for word to lemma free database

Tags: english, resource-request, lemmas, words

I want to write a simple program in Java, which being fed with English texts will be able to generate word usage statisitcs (e.g. topmost frequently used words in English).

For that purpose I need a database, which can provide me with [word to lemma] entries. Like:

```
went -> to go
me -> I
slowed -> to slow
```

and so on. Where can I get such a database?

Answer (score 1):

Denis, you might want to have a look at the perseus project database: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/opensource/download

Comment: So many tnx for the useful link!

Comment: @DenisKulagin: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

There are opens source tools that do that. They are called lemmatisers -  [Stanford Core NLP includes one.](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml)